# Run a python script when start up and SSH not log in

Tags: python, ssh, linux, mysql, systemd-startup

I am new to programming and doing a simple academic project with Raspberry Pi, I have a script which will monitor the changes of database and output the change with 2 different color LED.

I want it to be executed everytime raspberry pi reboot and SSH is not logged in.
Currently I have added the task in `crontab` but it's not executed when reboot. When I run in SSH command line, it works and when i logout `PuTTY`, it stop.

I have another script in `crontab` which working well when Pi reboot

My python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT) #red(away)
GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT) #green(home)

while True:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="ssss", passwd="sssss"$

    #cursor for select
    cur = db.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT status FROM home_mode ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    last_status = str(cur.fetchone())
    if last_status == "('HOME',)":
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(38, GPIO.LOW)
    elif last_status == "('AWAY',)":
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(38, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
            print "WRONG"
cur.close()

db.close()
```

The coding maybe very poor because I am really new in python even programming.
Hope anyone could give solution/advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A better choice would be to use [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) and its associated systemctl command.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **systemd** unit file to start the python script on boot up and run it as service. Just create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit monitor-db.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitor Database changes
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/full/path/to/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable and check the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable monitor-db.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status monitor-db.service
```

Reboot.